Why is updating Widget from App Intent when called by Live Activity inconsistent?
We have an app that user use to check in/out from work for example. We have a button in-app do do this. Now I'm trying to add buttons to our widgets and our new live activity so that users don't have to open the app.
It's crucial that the live activity and widgets always show the exact same state.
Otherwise it'll look pretty bad if a user has both a live activity and a widget showin at the same time.
However, we have noticed that sometimes, pressing the button in the live activity, running the app intent, will not always make the widget update (we call reloadAllTimelines()). The other way around, i.e. press the button on widget to update live activity always works. (they both call the same app intent)
When running it in debug mode on a phone from Xcode, it always works, but when running it just on the phone it's unreliable.
My first thought was, of course, that's related to the widget "budget", but according to the docsHERE, it should not be applied when interacting with a widget, calling an app intent.
My question:
HOW can I make my widget reliably refresh using an app intent invoked from a live activity??
Simplified code example of trying to update widget from app intent:
@MainActor
func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
    
    //some operation that updates the app state that the widget uses when updating its UI
    LiveActivityUtil.updateLiveActivity(updatedContent)
    
    //doesn't seem to do anything sometimes, unreliable
    WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
    return .result()
}


I believe the issue may still be with the budget. I was looking through the docs for a similar issue and ran across the same doc you linked. However, from my understanding, the part where it says it does not apply when "widget performs an app intent" is specific to the widget, and as such, activating it from a Live Activit does not count. Super unfortunate, and I hope they change this in the future.

Yeah. I've since talked to some other app developers, and we kind of came to that conclusion. I've also installed 10+ time/pomodoro apps and they all have the same issue. I'd call it embarrassing on Apple's part after so long time, it's a super obvious flaw IMO.

@Mathias Yea, I agree; it is super annoying. You would think that they would just update everything that uses the app intent at once. Hopefully, this is something they fix in the future since I would imagine it would not require any additional background activity if the live activity is already updating anyway...
